# how to convert 12 hours date and time to 24 hour date and time

Tags: node.js, momentjs

I have a output resulting from a string giving 12 hour format of date and time

Eg : "2021-04-16, 5:54 pm" as **string**

Is there a way to parse this string format to 24 hour date and time using moment js.
so it will look like
expected output : "2021-04-16 17:54"

I tried below code but didn't get expected output

```
moment("2021-04-16, 5:54 pm", 'hh:mm:ss A').format('HH:mm:ss')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you supply a format to `moment()`, the [format](http://%27YYYY-MM-DD%20hh:mm:ss%20P%27) has to match **the complete input date**, not just the time, so the correct format is: `'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss A'` instead off just the `hh:mm:ss A` part.

```js
const test = moment("2021-04-16, 5:54 pm", 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss A').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
console.log(test);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

```
2021-04-16 17:54:00
```

---

**Note**: [Moment.js should not be used for new projects](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/)

Answer (score 0):

Test this code and it will probably work

```
moment("2021-04-16 05:54 PM", 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss A').format('HH:mm:ss');
```